# Как нарисовать точку на экране с помощью java

Tags: java

Как отобразить определённый графический объект(маленькая точка) с помощью Java, без использования отдельного окна, просто точка на экране?

Comment: Ну тебе понадобится метод любой, чтобы он в себя включал Стринг, х, y, color.
Метод:
`public void onDraw(String s, double x, double y, int color) { (надеюсь ты сам тут поймешь что писать) }`
Все.

Comment: @ТимофейБобиков, не уверен, что в вопросе речь про Android.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Гуру:** что такое *точка на экране*?

**Ученик:** это точка на *экране*

**Гуру:** ну хорошо, что такое *экран*?

**Ученик:** ну это монитор, часть монитора...

**Гуру:** ок, никогда не замечали что экран всегда занят каким-то приложением?

**Ученик:** Ну да, но есть еще рабочий стол... а как же рабочий стол?

**Гуру:** рабочий стол - такое же приложение как и остальные.

**Ученик:** Эмм...

**Гуру:** когда-либо замечал, чтобы другое приложение рисовало в окне чужого приложения?

**Ученик:** бывает, но обычно это заканчивается плохо - зависанием системы и синим экраном смерти

**Гуру:** почему так происходит?

**Ученик:** потому что в рамках концепции оконной системы, каждое приложение имеет свое окно и не имеет доступа к окну чужого приложения

**Гуру:** то есть твой вопрос о точке на экране...

**Ученик:** да учитель, я понимаю, что это был глупый вопрос

**Гуру:** не совсем, всегда можно создать окно с невидимой границей и прозрачным фоном

**Ученик:** тогда в этом невидимом окне можно выводить любой графический примитив?

**Гуру:** именно, давай иди и почитай документацию по оконной системе Java

Comment: классная история, нужен такой опус :)